# How to properly architect app to display long forms with a lot of controls?

Tags: c#, architecture, ios, xamarin

Basically, I've been tasked to work on a Xamarin.iOS app (predominantly for tablets only) that would display a long scrollable form that contains ~200 controls (buttons, switches, text fields, etc...).

Normally, I would create an instance of the control, assign values to it's properties and then add the control to the view to display but with 200 controls, it seems like a lot of redundancy and long classes.

How can I best architect this app to prevent redundancy or make the controls populate dynamically?

E.g.

Instead of

```
UILabel label1 = new UILabel(); 
label1.Text = "label text"; 


UILabel label2 = new UILabel(); 
label2.Text = "label text";

//...
//then do this like 200 times to show labels with different names
```

Can I do something like this?

```
//in a foreach with amount of controls 

UILabel label = new UILabel(); 
label.Text = dynamicallyGeneratedText;
```

But in general, what's the best way to architect an app with long, scrollable form that the user has to fill out? What are some ways I can make my code more dynamic and less hardcoded?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help. http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/150450955-how-many-form-fields.html

Comment: Redesign the view... There's something named UX.

Comment: We need more information, what kind of inputs are they?
Are they related at all? Distinct?

Comment: one page with 200 differents controls on a tablet ? Unless if this a kind of list like Ewan's answer suggest, who would want to use something like this ? You'd better go by grouping them and having a navigation system between those groups.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need this many elements, then you should probably make the interface data-driven instead of entirely in code. This means that instead of 200 instances of `new UILabel()` in your code, you would have an array or other data structure that contained the text/ID of each label, then you would just use a for loop to iterate over these creating a new instance for each one. So instead of 400 lines creating labels you would just have 4 lines something like:

```
for(label : labels) {
    UILabel uilabel = new UILabel(); 
    uilabel.Text = label.text;
}
```

Once your UI is data-driven then this also opens up the possibility of the data being loaded from a configuration-file or from a database, so you can change the UI without having to modify or recompile the code at all.

Comment: I agree. FWIW, in an asp.net web project with such (really) long forms I had decided to build them dynamically based on data stored in (the project's) database. In other words, each form was *described* in the database and built on the fly. Nevertheless, the variation of form controls was very limited (only labels, textboxes, checkboxes and buttons).

Answer (score 0):

ListView  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/

But, getting this to be performant has been a notorious bug bear for Xamarin. You would be well advised to thoroughly test for performance on multiple real devices before committing to be able to produce the design in Xamarin.